# How can I have file similar to colors.xml in Xamarin Forms like android

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I collect all color codes in single file, as we could do in Android & 
using them by referencing that file. For now I am doing this in xaml

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter name" PlaceholderColor="#177245" ></Entry>
<Entry Placeholder="Enter name" PlaceholderColor="#C04000" ></Entry>
```

In `Xamarin.Forms` I am looking something like

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter name" PlaceholderColor="@color/DimGray" ></Entry>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App.xaml you can create a resource dictionary and declare the colors in there:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.App" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="ThemeColor>#177245</Color>
            <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor>#C04000</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now in your element you simply set the color property as follows:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter name" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource ThemeColor}" />
```

Comment: Your answer helped me. Still Can't we have simple .cs or .xml class to do so.

Comment: Well, I see no reason why one couldn't write a xml config file reader, which reads available files on startup and add them as merged resource dictionaries.
However, this doesn't come out of the box.

Another option would be css styling: https://xamarinhelp.com/css-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I wonder if CSS works the same as in web, and you need to specify !important :)

Answer (score 1):

Create file with your colors:

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    public class ColorConsts
    {
        public Color MyColor1 { get; } = Color.Gray;
        public Color MyColor2 { get; } = Color.Blue;
    }
```

Add object to resources and bind colors:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:ColorConsts x:Key="colors"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>  


    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter name" PlaceholderColor="{Binding Source={StaticResource colors},Path=MyColor1}" ></Entry>
    </StackLayout>
```

If you don't want to add to all pages define it in app.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App16.App"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App16"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:ColorConsts x:Key="colors"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Same approach can be used for numeric consts, localization and can parametrise  everything in you xaml.

Pros of this approach is that you can make your consts class INotifyPropertyChanged and change colors at runtime.

Comment: Don't we have something more easy like `PlaceholderColor="@color/DimGray"` without declaring `local` in each file.

Comment: Define your constants object in resource dictionary and merge it to all pages.